# how can i print a string that contains integers and commas only in unix?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a file that contains the below:

```
echo apple25,orange23,banana22 > file1
```

I am trying to print integers and commas only.

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' file
```

desired result

```
25,23,22
```

Comment: So what is your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close; you just need to add the commas to your character class.

```
sed 's/[^0-9,]*//g' file
```

The regex now says "replace any characters that aren't 0-9 or a comma with nothing".

Comment: `sed 's/[^0-9,]*//g' file1` =>  `25,23,22` - looks right to me.

Comment: Check your input - I suspect you included "file1" in your input file somehow. The input should be `apple25,orange23,banana22`, not `echo apple25,orange23,banana22 > file1`. The latter is the command to generate the input data.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr` (assuming you want newlines too).

```
$ tr -dc '[0-9],\n' <file
```